# Embarrassingly basic RStudio Dilemma -- "Error: object 'num' not found"

Tags: r, rstudio

I've encountered a strange problem with RStudio. Using the following code in the **console**:

```
test <- 'This is a test'
test
num <- 2
num
```

it properly returns the string and number associated with test and num, respectively. Furthermore, the variables are registered in the "Environment" tab.

The problem arises when I go to run a script. After creating an R File with the identical code and pressing 'Run', the only console output is:

```
> num
Error: object 'num' not found
```

And the variables are not registered in the "Environment" tab.

**Why is my code working in the console, but not in an R script?**

I am sorry for such a basic question, but I am new to RStudio and this is incredibly frustrating. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly does your R script look like? How are you "running" it? Does it work in the standard R GUI?

Comment: With the `Run` button, you need to either be on the line you're running or highlight the code. I think you want the `Source` button, or highlight the code you want to run

Comment: To be sure, instead of the run button, you can write in the console `source("theScript.R")`

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too when I started with RStudio. the answer was simple. I guess you probably forgot to run line "num <- 2"

After you typed the two lines in the script.

```
num <- 2 
num
```

go back to the first line num<-2, and press ctrl+enter
the console will show as below

```
> num <- 2
```

then go to the second line num in the script, and press ctrl+enter, you will have your console output.

```
> num
 [1] 2
```

if you didn't run the first line but only the second line in the console, num is not being created and the "2" is not given to num. that's why it shows "Error: object 'num' not found" in the console.

Answer (score 1):

This may happens with beginners who is new to R Programming. Whenever you save and run the program through Rstudio, the run button or ctrl+Enter only runs the single line or where you kept your cursor. if you want to run your complete program without single execution, just select all the code with ctrl+A or with your mouse and Run your program the error will remove.

Comment: Why is that a thing? Is there no button to click to execute all of the script in one go? Having a button to only run a single line might be useless, but it's also very useful to have a button to run all of the code (instead of marking it all).

Answer (score 0):

There's an argument `local` within `source()`. I think if you set it to `TRUE` then operations within source will be able to find the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by running the R code line by line and then re-running it all as one. It is important to do that if anything cha

Answer (score -1):

You have to save the script after any updates. Then it will run the whole script without needing to select all.